# How can I reduce the amount of technical high risk work in projects?

Tags: software-development

Typically, my projects involve a challenging technical problem. In my latest project this is a set of offline [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) screens, which was scope creep of 50% of the total project estimate. I reviewed options, which were basically AngularJS and some offline library or building my own offline CRUD system. I opted for the latter, because I build my own CRUD system in the past and had negative experiences with technical limitations of fairly new libraries. My gut feeling is I was wrong.
I'd like to reduce the amount of high risk work in current projects. Three options come to mind:

- Use new technology in a hobby project only
- Find clients to pay for research work, maybe on a lower rate
- Do research work on open source projects I interact with

Has anyone used any of these three methods? What was your experience with it and which method would you recommend?

Comment: Hi, what's your question or did I miss it? :)

Comment: I have added a question now.

Comment: Hi jdog, welcome to PM:SE. This site is not well suited to questions like this which are canvassing for opinions and experiences. The site is a Q&A site- you ask a question (which should be definitively answerable) and (hopefully) you get answers. There are questions of merit within your question- for example "how can I reduce the amount of high risk work in projects" etc. But as it is currently written it is too broad and mostly opinion-based, and may therefore be closed. Can you try to edit the question to ask a single answerable question and perhaps split others out to other questions?

Comment: Yep can do tomorrow, can i have 24h please?

Comment: Jdog, even if the question is closed, you can still revise and nominate for re-open. "close" is a misnomer for "revise".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of your three options, I like the open source project the best as it gives you a specific problem to solve, it will probably be peer reviewed, and gives you OSD credibility.  That said...

I think this boils down to "How do I limit risk to a project when there is new/unknown tech involved?".

1. Determine if new technology is really required.  There is *usually* less risk with tried & true.
2. If new tech needs to be used, budget time for a prototype at the start of the project.  This will show you if this is feasible early on, and also give you some experience with the tech and give a better idea of how easy it is to develop with.  This will help validate the other estimates later in the project.
3. Check and see if your country provides R&D tax credits.  For example in Canada the [Scientific Research & Experimental Development](http://sbinfocanada.about.com/od/taxdeductions/a/identifySREDgf.htm) tax credit can be over 40% of your valid R&D expenses!